# how to get or set object's attribute from a list in maya python?

Tags: python, list, maya, getattr

```
list = cmds.ls(sl = True)
```

How to get or set Attr e.g `translateY` for objects in `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pymel it's a lot simpler...

```
sel = selected()

for i in sel:
    print i.ty.get()
    i.ty.set(i.ty.get() + 1)
```

Comment: I like this one, learned a lot from it when I started: [Maya-Python-Games-Film-Referenc](http://www.amazon.com/Maya-Python-Games-Film-Reference/dp/0123785782) And there's also plenty of documentation [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/).

Comment: oh yes i have this ebook and i'm chapter 3 right now and it's great.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a Maya specific issue that I don't know about, there are a couple of ways to do this in Python:

```
for myObject in myList:

    # directly getting and setting attribute
    myObject.translateY = 30.0     # set
    a = myObject.translateY        # get

    # alternatively, via setattr and getattr built-in functions.
    setattr(myObject, "translateY", 40.0)
    # getter which Raises exception if myObject has no "translateY" attr:
    a = getattr(myObject, "translateY")
    # getter which supplies defaultVal if myObject has no "translateY" attr
    a = getattr(myObject, "translateY", defaultVal)
```

As an aside, it is bad form to call your variable "list", as this name will shadow Python's built-in list function. Better to use something like "myList" instead.

Comment: import  maya.cmds as cm


mylist = cm.ls (sl = True)

for myobject in mylist:
 a = cm.getAttr('myobject,translateY')

print a

Comment: # Error: line 1: No object matches name: translateY
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 7, in <module>
# ValueError: No object matches name: translateY #

Comment: Don't use cm.getAttr('myobject,translateY'). Use cm.getAttr(myobject, 'translateY'). Quotes around the attr name, no quotes around the object name.